# docker swarm service accessible on swarm host but not on the LAN IP address

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 2 nodes `10.0.0.2` and `10.0.0.3` setup as swarm cluster.

The service was created with `docker service create --name nginx --publish published=80,target=80 nginx:alpine`

I tried from both nodes in the docker swarm cluster, `curl` works when i do `curl localhost` from both nodes.

However, when i tried to access from another host (not in cluster) on the local network, I can't access  via, say `10.0.0.2` or `10.0.0.3` (port 80).

Comment: can you check if firewall is running on the machines and preventing access on those ports?

Comment: @akazuko the firewall is off (ubuntu and ufw)

Comment: If these are hosted on cloud, do you have any network rules added to VPC?

Comment: @akazuko it's just a small pc at home. no vpc.